# jQuery: How to detect if mouse click location is outside of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mousedown

I have this code which detects any mouse click on a website:

```
$(document).mousedown(function() {
    console.log("you clicked somewhere.");
});
```

How do I make it to only trigger an action if the clicked location is outside of `#specificDiv`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(document).mousedown(function(event) {
 var specificDiv= $("#specificDiv");
 if (specificDiv.is(event.target))
   console.log("you clicked specificDiv.");
});
```

Comment: `e.currentTarget` for click on children of the id specificDiv in event bubbling phase

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).mousedown(function() {
    if($(this).closest('#specificDiv').length == 0){
    }
});
```

Comment: While this post may answer the question, it is still a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, some links to the relevant documentation. Answers with good explanations and references are usually more useful both to the current OP and to the future visitors. Full detailed answers are also more likely to attract positive votes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `target` property of the event object.

`target` points to the element on which the event generated

```js
var myDiv = $("#myDiv");
$(document).mousedown(function(ev) {
  if(myDiv.is(ev.target)){
    console.log("you clicked on myDiv.");
  }else{
    console.log("you clicked somewhere.");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color:#00FF00;" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
$(document).mousedown(function (ev) {
    var $target = $(ev.target);
    var $specificDiv = $target.closest('#specificDiv');

    if (!$specificDiv || !$specificDiv.length) {
        // clicked location is outside
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#your_div').mousedown(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); //Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.
});

$(document).mousedown(function(e){
    console.log("you clicked somewhere.");
});
```

Comment: why mousedown and no explanation added